# Android playlpm file editor

Tags: android, file, editor, system

I have pull the 'playlpm' file from a device to my computer. But I am not able to open and edit it with notepad (lots of unknown characters), can someone suggest a way to edit the file and push back to the device? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit playlpm file. Just rename it to playlpm.old and create a new playlpm file. It will be enough.

You can create new playlpm file in this way. (^D means pressing ctrl key + D)

```
root@q7lteskt:/system/bin # cat > playlpm
cat > playlpm
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
^D
```